# How to upload/download file into Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Object Storage(OCI) from android app

Tags: java, android, oracle, cloud, storage

I am trying to use Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Object Storage from android app. their documents are not understandable and I didn't find any proper tutorial on net.
I found this gibhub project(https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk) but could understand which one I need to use/there is a config file to create request so where to store that config file in app,

Please tell me whether it is possible to use oracle storage in android app or not
if its possible means, I need all steps/sample code to upload/download and delete operations in java.